# Flex List auto width

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, layout, flex4.5

Is it possible for a Flex List to adjust its width automatically based on content it's displaying ? The number of rows is dynamic so I would like the List to automatically adjust it's width based on its content. I have tried setting width="100%" which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like by subclassing the List, then listening for the collectionChange event.  You can then look for the longest item and set the List width appropriately.